# GoAccess not recognizing --keep-db-files and others

Tags: goaccess

I have installed **goaccess-1.0.2** along with the ncurses and the optional dependencies provided by goaccess man page on my **Ubuntu 16.04** OS.

I am successfully able to parse logs with the following command: `goaccess -f access.log -a`.  I am able to create logs into an html report with the following command `goaccess -f access.log -a -o report.html`.

I am **not able** to successfully parse data into real time html output with the following command `goaccess -f access.log -o report.html --real-time-html`.  However, it does start to parse, but at some point it freezes.  So I assume the data is to large for memory.

So I wanted to learn how to parse data to disk.  I used the following command `goaccess -f access.log --keep-db-files`.  I received the following feedback: **goaccess: unrecognized option '--keep-db-files'**

I thought maybe I missed dependencies, but I checked back through the goaccess man page and it doesn't seem that I am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, it does start to parse, but at some point it freezes. So I assume the data is to large for memory.

If you are successfully parsing the same log with `goaccess -f access.log -a`, then using `--real-time-html` shouldn't make any difference. Check your memory usage with `top` or take a look at `dmesg`.

> I used the following command goaccess -f access.log --keep-db-files. I received the following feedback: goaccess: unrecognized option '--keep-db-files'

You need to compile GoAccess with btree support. To do this, you need to install [TokyoCabinet](https://goaccess.io/faq) and then build goaccess from source:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libtokyocabinet-dev
$ curl http://tar.goaccess.io/goaccess-1.0.2.tar.gz | tar xvz
$ cd goaccess-1.0.2/
$ ./configure --enable-utf8 --enable-geoip --enable-tcb=btree
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: Thank you.  I already had the optional dependencies installed.  I went through everything again.  I was missing zlib-devel.  Ughh...  Thanks Kayla for the feedback!